# Filter Google BigQuery columns by regex filter

Tags: python, pandas, performance, google-bigquery

Currently I`m struggling in creating fast and optimized query in Google Big Query.

Assume, having table, having 10k rows and 4k columns:

```
    | TP_001_A | TP_001_B | TP_002_A | TP_002   |    ...   | TP_099_B | 
----+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
 1  |   0.33   |   0.33   |   0.33   |   0.33   |   0.33   |   0.37   | 
 2  |   0.33   |   0.33   |   0.31   |   0.33   |   0.33   |   0.33   |
 3  |   0.33   |   0.33   |   0.33   |   0.33   |   0.33   |   0.33   |
 4  |   0.35   |   0.33   |   0.33   |   0.33   |   0.34   |   0.33   |
...
9999|   0.33   |   0.33   |   0.33   |   0.33   |   0.33   |   0.33   |
```

My task is to select columns based on regex filter (e.g. only these which name starts from TP_001), resulting in such table:

```
    | TP_001_A | TP_001_B |
----+----------+----------+
 1  |   0.33   |   0.33   |
 2  |   0.33   |   0.33   |
 3  |   0.33   |   0.33   |
 4  |   0.35   |   0.33   |
...
9999|   0.33   |   0.33   |
```

By now I`ve worked this around and query whole table, and then filter it using pandas library, which is slow, because of downloading time and overall pandas slowness in big tables.

After searching the web I found out that column names can be retrieved by query like:

```
SELECT column_name 
FROM my_view.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE table_name="my_table"
```

Where I can use REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL function, and filter proper column names, but it is giving me separate table which is hard to use in main query.

But this solution has one issue: is is processing a lot of data (indication shows 10MB, but it looks like a lot) despite it being quite fast.

Is there any proper way of doing such query or other way to optimize retrieving only filtered columns?

Comment: If you are already using python, query Information_SCHEMA, loop through results and filter to get the needed column names, and then build a new select statement from those results, then execute a query against the new string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any proper way of doing such query (Filter Google BigQuery columns by regex filter) ...

There is no way of doing such a query with pure BigQuery SQL - you can [submit feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=0) if you wish.

Meantime, you can use any [BigQuery Client Library](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries) of your choice to build the needed select statement programmatically and execute it - super simple and doable option

> ... or other way to optimize retrieving only filtered columns?

If for some reason you bound to using pure BQ SQL - the only option I see is flattening as in example below (with slightly modified dummy data from your question)

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 id, 0.3301 TP_001_A, 0.3305 TP_001_B, 0.3309 TP_002_A, 0.3313 TP_002, 0.3317 TP_003, 0.3721 TP_099_B UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 0.3302, 0.3306, 0.3110, 0.3314, 0.3318, 0.3322 UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 0.3303, 0.3307, 0.3311, 0.3315, 0.3319, 0.3323 UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 0.3504, 0.3308, 0.3312, 0.3316, 0.3420, 0.3324 
)
SELECT id, TRIM(kv.key, '"') col, kv.value
FROM `project.dataset.table` t,
UNNEST(ARRAY(
  SELECT AS STRUCT SPLIT(kv, ':')[OFFSET(0)] key, SPLIT(kv, ':')[OFFSET(1)] value
  FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(TRIM(TO_JSON_STRING(t), '{}'))) kv
  WHERE STARTS_WITH(SPLIT(kv, ':')[OFFSET(0)], '"TP_001') 
)) kv
-- ORDER BY id
```

with result

```
Row id  col         value    
1   1   TP_001_A    0.3301   
2   1   TP_001_B    0.3305   
3   2   TP_001_A    0.3302   
4   2   TP_001_B    0.3306   
5   3   TP_001_A    0.3303   
6   3   TP_001_B    0.3307   
7   4   TP_001_A    0.3504   
8   4   TP_001_B    0.3308
```

From my experience - above output is much more useful for most practical use-cases involving dynamic list of columns than if presented in columns

Obviously, you can replace `STARTS_WITH(..., '"TP_001')` with REGEXP_CONTAINS if you have more complex filter